# Python regex on space separated key value blocks to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, parsing

I have large multiline text of key-value strings separated by spaces and divided into blocks by using ==== characters.
For each block, I want to create a dictionary with key-value

Basically, I found myself more struggling writing the regex rather than creating the dictionary, I used this `r'^(\w+)\s*(.*)'` to get key and value as whatever comes after space, but I don't know how to separate the text into blocks by ====.
Values are fake obviously, however, each value can overflow to a new line, as you can see below.

See the text below:

```
name                  jcento                                                                                                                                                                        
server_param          uptime=2,load=2, \                                                                                                                                                
                      mem=1,io=10
info_values           cpu=5,io=1,load=0, \                                                                                                                                    
                      core=8, mem=22724, \                                                                                                                                                         

info_value1           10                                                                                                                                                                                            
info_value2           banana                                                                                                                                                                                     
info_value3           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
projects              proj1 proj2 proj3 \
                      proj4

info_value5           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value6           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value7           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value8           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value9           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                      
================================================================================                                                                                                                                   
name                  jcento                                                                                                                                                                        
server_param          uptime=2,load=2, \                                                                                                                                                
                      mem=1,io=10
info_values           cpu=5,io=10,load=0, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                      core=8, mem=22724, \                                                                                                                                                         

info_value1           10                                                                                                                                                                                            
info_value2           banana                                                                                                                                                                                     
info_value3           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
projects              proj1 proj2 proj3 \
                      proj4

info_value5           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value6           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value7           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value8           NONE                                                                                                                                                                                         
info_value9           NONE
```

I expect the output to be a list of dictionaries `[{name:'jcento', server_param: 'uptime=2,load=2,mem=1,io=1', ...}, {name:'jcento5',....}]`

Also, if possible, to create a regex that generates A dictionary from key=value of name, value= value of projects, for example :

`{jcento: 'proj1 proj2 proj3 proj4', jcento5: 'proj1 proj2 proj3 proj4'}`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think ‘I know, I’ll use regular expressions.’ Now they have two problems." – Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Would you consider making your life easier by using an approach without regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want each section separated by a "===========" boundary to be its unique dict in a list of dicts.
You did not provide any code, but seeing you employ this regex to find you key/value pairs

```
r'^(\w+)\s*(.*)'
```

I assume you grab the two groups and simply pass their respective values as `newDict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)`

The issue comes down to how you are reading the data. In this approach, I would simply read the file line by line, but since your values can be multiline, I am already unsure how you even get the correct groupings from the regex you provided. "(.*)" should be greedy as hell and return you much more than what you would like.

Provided all line-jumps are marked by "\", you could write a regex that can take this into account, like this:
Replace "(.*)" with "([\w,=]+(\s\\s?[\w,=]+)?)"

However, I would probably just make certain adjustments to the text file as I read it in, to have all datapoints stored on a single line before iterating over it and capturing with your previous regex.
Added bonus: 
You can add a line in the iteration function that matches "=========" and initialize a new dictionary while adding the old to the list.

```
   import re
   final_list = []

   def makeDict(fl, data):
        kvPattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s*(.*)')
        newDict = {}
        for line in data:
            if line.startswith("============="):
                fl.append(newDict)
                newDict = {}
            elif kvPattern.search(line):
                match = kvPattern.search(line)
                newDict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)

        return fl

    final_list = makeDict(final_list, data)
```

If you feel cocky, you can use "else" instead of "elif", too.
Or even better, wrap the whole thing in Try-blocks to check wether any datapoints don't match your regex pattern